# How to add a submenu item in submenu of Context menu

Tags: c#, contextmenustrip

I have a context menu that has some items like `A, B C, D and E`. Now D and E also has a sub menu items.

Ex `D has I and J`

```
E has K and L
```

and same K and L has some sub menu items. For example:

```
K has M

L has T
```

So my context menu will look like this..

```
A   
B    
C   
D --> I    
      J    
E --> K --> M   
      L --> T
```

So my question is how to add `M` and `T` items in toolstripitems which are `K` and `L`.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984254(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Here is sample code that creates menu like `A --> B --> C`:

```
ContextMenuStrip menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
ToolStripMenuItem menuItemA = new ToolStripMenuItem("A");
menu.Items.Add(menuItemA);
ToolStripMenuItem menuItemB = new ToolStripMenuItem("B");
menuItemA.DropDownItems.Add(menuItemB);
ToolStripMenuItem menuItemC = new ToolStripMenuItem("C");
menuItemB.DropDownItems.Add(menuItemC);
this.ContextMenuStrip = menu;
```

If items you deal with `ToolStripItem` you will have to cast it to `ToolStripMenuItem`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that should be very simple to do using Windows Form Designer with the following steps:

Click on MenuItem E and Add MenuItem K just by typing 'K' in the text field shown by the designer (saying 'Type Here')

Now Click on MenuItem K and Add MenuItem M just by typing 'M'

Hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add sub menu by using code behind

example

```
(myContextMenuStrip.Items["Item Status"] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add("Submenu1", null, new EventHandler(gridcontexsubMenu_ItemClicked));
```

and refer the following link for context menu handler

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776881.aspx